# How do we show the busy indicator in a VSTS Widget?

Tags: tfs, widget, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm creating a VSTS Widget which also has a configuration widget.  I would like to know how to set the busy indicator as the data rendering is taking a bit of time.

[From the API:](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/vss/references/vss_sdk_interfaces/iextensioninitializationoptions)  It states this about the VSS.INIT option...

```
IExtensionInitializationOptions
Last Update: 1/24/2017
Defined in vss.d.ts

Options for the extension's initialization method

Members
    explicitNotifyLoaded: boolean. Optional. 

Set to true if the extension willexplicitly call notifyLoadSucceeded or       
notifyLoadFailed itself to indicate that the extension is done loading
(stops UI loading indicator in the host). If false (the default) the
extension is considered ready as soon as init is called.
```

But we already have set this option as follows:

```
VSS.init({
    explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
    usePlatformStyles: true,
    usePlatformScripts: true
```

We never see the UI loading indicator.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VSS.init()` is used to perform an initial handshake/setup with the host window. When use `explicitNotifyLoaded` to indicate that we will notify the host manually when the extension is done loading. This is used for the loading indicator.  `VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded()` is called later to indicate that the extension is loaded.

So please make sure you call `VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded()` later, so that the system knows that you’re all done.

Also give a try with [ready()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/core-sdk#method_ready) method, which *register a callback that gets called once the initial setup/handshake has completed*.  Some samples for you reference:

- [Using TypeScript to load modules in a Visual Studio Team Services
  Extension](https://freerangeeggs.net/2016/03/10/using-typescript-to-load-modules-in-a-visual-studio-team-services-extension/)
- [vsts-extension-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/contributions-guide/context.html)

Comment: What worked "kind-of" for me was to include markup that indicated loading was happening by adding a div about the chart element, but still within the div for the widget.  The problem is that VSS takes full control until after load is complete, so there's only a tiny period of time to gain screen time.  It did help that all work was asynchronous, so I get about 2 seconds of show time...  I simple set a timeout delay of about 2 seconds to turn off the loading indicator.  I'll work with the ready method today.